# Accessing javaScript object using [ ] notation

Tags: javascript

What is difference  between below:

```
var ourDog = {
    "name": "Camper"
};
```

and

```
var ourDog = {
    name: "Camper",
};
```

And how it is able to return *Camper* for `ourDog["name"]` in both cases.

Is there any conversion happening behind the scene, when we access object properties with `[]` notation?

Comment: you can use bracket notation if object `keys` are dynamic

Comment: If the property name has a space then `var ourDog = {
    "first name": "Camper"
};` then it won't work without quotes

Comment: I'm clear with it's usage, my doubt is how it yields same result for both object; I mean with quotes and without quotes.

Comment: Anything in the square brackets is converted to a string. So when you give it a string, there should be no conversion needed. Some older version of Safari I think had some performance issues with the brackets, but that was quite a while back. In the literal notation, it's just alternate syntax. This is resolved before the code runs.

Comment: it's basically the same.

Comment: As to how it's able to return the same value with both syntax, it's simply because that's how they designed the language.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer-static-semantics-propname)

> PropertyDefinition : PropertyName : AssignmentExpression
>
> 1. Return PropName of PropertyName.

This part of spec suggests the formal syntax of the property name with its value.

Also, before that [this part of the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer) suggest that propertyName could be `literalPropertyName` **which need not be described as a string**.

> PropertyName[Yield] :
>
> > LiteralPropertyName
> >
> > ComputedPropertyName[?Yield]
>
> LiteralPropertyName :
>
> > IdentifierName
> >
> > StringLiteral
> >
> > NumericLiteral

This is why you will get same result for both `name` and `"name"`.

However, if the property name is `first name`, then you need to use the string otherwise you will get a compilation error since after the property name a colon  `:` is expected.

```
//correct syntax
var ourDog = {
    "first name": "Camper"
};

//incorrect syntax
var ourDog = {
    first name: "Camper" //since after first there is no colon so there will be  compilation error
};
```

Comment: Thanks Gurvinder +1! It will be very helpful if you could further describe in simple language, found it bit difficult to understand as newbie.

Comment: In simple words, JS engine expects a literal property name without quotes if the value is valid primitive value, else it needs to be in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer

A property name can only be an identifier name (i.e. identifiers + reserved words), a string literal, or a numeric literal.

you cant use a numeric literal with dot notation but bracket notation works:

```
var ourDog = {
    123: "Camper",
};
```

Output

```
ourDog[123] // Camper
```

but

```
ourDog.123 // SyntaxError
```

for more information take a look into [this](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-properties)

Answer (score 0):

Property names must be strings. This means that non-string objects cannot be used as keys in the object. Any non-string object, including a number, is typecasted into a string via the toString method

```
var object = {};
object['1'] = 'value';
console.log(object[1]);
```

This outputs "value", since 1 is type-casted into '1'.

Example is from MDN